# Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongo

Tags: mongodb

I’m new to AngularJS and new to Deployd. I’m running windows 7.

I ran the following command:

```
C:\books\ProAngular\TEMP\pro-angularjs-master\Chapter 01>dpd -p 5500 sportsstore
\app.dpd dashboard
```

Here is my error:

> C:\books\ProAngular\TEMP\pro-angularjs-master\Chapter 01>dpd -p 5500 sportsstore
>   \app.dpd dashboard
>   deployd CLI version 2.0.2
>   starting deployd
>   Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongo
>   d option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html)

I’ve looked online and at stackoverflow. I still can’t get the app to run.

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your MongoDB installation path to the variable PATH.
Go to system properties -> advanced -> in the system variables tab look for the variable PATH and click edit.
Add the MongoDB path at the end of what you already have and save.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of 2 reasons.

1. mongodb path is not available in PATH variable
2. mongodb might be runnign already. In this case, kill the mongodb process from task manager/processes and run dpd again

This works both on mac and windows

Answer (score 0):

use the command bellow

```
dpd --mongod "MONGODB_HOME\mongod.exe"
```

Make sure to replace `MONGODB_HOME` with the right path.

That should work

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to shutdown (stop) mongod:

I’m running Ubuntu 18.04, by default my mongod is running after boot up. To check the “status” of mongod type: service mongod status

You should see something like this where active (running) is in green:
Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-10-05 19:39:33 CDT; 2min 47s ago

Then type: service mongod stop, this will stop mongod
Now check the “status” again by typing: service mongod status

You should see something like this where inactive (dead) is in green:
Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2019-10-05 19:45:14 CDT; 1s ago

Now when you type the dpd command you should not get a mongod error.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
cd sportsstore
dpd --host "127.0.0.1" -P '27017' -n "mongodb" -u " " -s " "
```